# How to get all cookies of the new firefox browser instance

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cookies, watir

Am using the following to create a firefox driver

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['general.useragent.override'] = agent
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile
```

Making request:-

```
browser.goto "http://3454kdf.blogspot.com/"
```

Its redirecting to amazon site and getting cookie value from amazon site.

But i want to get the cookies of this page(http://3454kdf.blogspot.com/) which is loaded. How can i get it.

To get cookies, am use the following:-

```
browser.cookies.to_a

browser.driver.manage.all_cookies
```

If am making request with three different url using firefox profile. Then i want to get all  the cookies stored in browser. How can i get it?

Comment: Are you saying that the code is not doing what you want or are you answering your own question within the question?

Comment: @JustinKo browser.cookies getting current url cookies only not all browser cookies(cookies stored already by other requests)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of all the cookies on the page, use the all_cookies method:

```
driver.manage.all_cookies.each do |cookie|
    puts cookie[:name]
end
```

Comment: I want to get all cookies stored in browser not cookies in current page.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do that, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you can access the cookies only set by your site/current page. You can not access all the cookies stored in the browser.

Comment: Is there any way to store all request details and cookie details in local file and fetch from it.